# How to fetch a single data base entry with Redux and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm learning React and Redux. And I may have a really basic question.

I want to get a single story from my backend using the Redux function `mapStateToProps` (#1). So I wrote the function `getSingleStory` which takes the id as argument and returns the story data (#2). When I log the response data of the `getSingleStory` in the console, it shows me the correct story fetched from the backend (#3):

[image: Response data from the getSingleStory Function (console.log was executed in the action file)]

However, if the console logs the story array in my component (#4), it outputs all stories from my database, not just the single story I wanted to fetch (see picture). If I want to display  'Story.title', in my render function of course it does not work.

[image: Story Props of the component]

If someone could explain to me why in the response data the single story is included and in the `const story = this.props.story;` all stories suddenly appear, that would help me a lot.

```
export class StoryDetails extends Component {

componentDidMount() {                                             // #2
   this.props.getSingleStory(this.props.match.params.id);
 }

 render() {

   const story = this.props.story;
   console.log (story);                            // #4
   return (
          <div>

              <h2>{story.title}</h2>
         </div>
   );
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({story: state.story});                    //#1

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 { getSingleStory, deleteStory}
)(StoryDetails);
```

Action

```
// GET SINGLE STORY
export const getSingleStory = id => (dispatch, getState) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get( apiBase + `/story/${id}/`, tokenConfig(getState))
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_SINGLE_STORY,
                story: res.data

            }, console.log (res.data));                                //#3
            resolve(res);
         })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
            reject(err);
        });
   });
};
```

Reducer

```
import { GET_SINGLE_STORY } from "../actions/types.js";


export default function (state = {}, action) {  
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_SINGLE_STORY:                                     
      return action.story;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess multiple stories were returned from backend.

Comment: Exactly, but i want to get a single story. But i dont know why it returns multiple stories. @Khabir

Comment: In that case, you must return single story from backend. please use something like return stories.first()